# In Home component of react+redux app, this.props.posts is undefined after calling action getPosts() on componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a blog-style application. I am running a django server and trying to make a react-redux frontend. I am using redux-devtools and when I comment out the error code, redux seems to have the data in the state. Not sure what is going wrong. Also, I am using redux-thunk and axios to communicate with the backend. I am pretty much copying from a youtube tutorial.
This is the reducer reducers/posts.js

```
    import {GET_POSTS} from "../actions/types";

    const initialState = {
        posts: []
    }

    export default function(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case GET_POSTS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                posts: action.payload
            }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

this is the action actions/posts.js

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import {GET_POSTS} from "./types";

    export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
        axios.get('/get/posts/').then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
    }
```

this is reducers/index.js

```
    import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
    import posts from "./posts";
    export default combineReducers({
        posts
    });
```

this is store.js

```
    import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import rootReducer from './reducers';

    const initialState = {};

    const middleware = [thunk];

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
    );
    export default store;
```

this is components/Home.js (ERROR HERE)

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {getPosts} from '../actions/posts';
    class Home extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getPosts();
        }
        render() {
            console.log(this.props.posts); //undefined
            const posts = this.props.posts.map(post => (
                <div className="post">
                    <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                    <p>{post.message}</p>
                </div>
                )
            )
            return (
                {posts}
            )
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        posts: state.posts // I have tried state.posts
    // and state.posts.posts. I think 
    //state.posts might be undefined which is 
    //causing this.props.posts to be undefined in the component
    });
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getPosts})(Home);
```

ANSWER: I found out that render is called multiple times and the first time it is called, this.props.posts is undefined, so I put an if statement for if this.props.posts is undefined and if it is not, I render the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your return inside `Home` component do this:

```
return (
        {this.posts.length > 0 && posts}
)
```

Your initial render, is trying to render an array of elements that are not being yet fetched from the server. All fetch calls to web apis and to backend servers are async which means they will execute as soon as the stack frame of the JS engine is free. Adding the conditional statement will allow you to do an extra `check`which will rerender the page since the data will be fetched and stored to your reducer. Additionally, when not sure what is the state/shape of your redux store, you can always console log it like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
 console.log(state);
 return {
  posts: state.posts
 }
}
```

Comment: wait the return in home would return a boolean, can you please clarify. Also,, state.posts is an empty array on console.log. I am pretty sure that django's return should have one post, but redux is not getting it.

Comment: this expression: `true && value` will render the `value`, this is not a react thing but pure javascript. It's one of many ways that react implements for conditional rendering. `false && value` will render nothing. The console log inside mapStateToProps is there just to see the shape of the state object.